# UIsearchBar show results but when I press something that didnt exist the app crush

Tags: xcode, core-data, storyboard, uisearchbar

I try understand what happens from some tutorials but unfortunately I am not found the answer.
I think that the  problem may be that i didn't have **IF** in case that I get nil in search result.

**the error is:**
'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'

I use that method:

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    //removes previos search result
    [[self searchResults]removeAllObjects];

    for (Books *book in [self.fetchResultsController fetchedObjects])
    {
            if([self searchResults] != nil)
            {
                NSComparisonResult result = [book.title compare:searchText
                                                   options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch)
                                                     range:NSMakeRange(0, [searchText length])];
                if (result == NSOrderedSame )
                {
                        [self.searchResults addObject:book];
                }
            }
        }
}
```

also can find my full project at the git:
https://github.com/dennis87/git_bookList

**edit:**
when I try put if like this one

if ([scope isEqualToString:@"All"] || [book.title isEqualToString:scope])

the app crush without let me press any thing..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that  `numberOfSectionsInTableView` always returns `1` for the search results table, even if there are no search results. The crash happens in `titleForHeaderInSection`:

```
return [[[self searchResults] objectAtIndex:section] author];
```

because the object at index 0 is accessed from an empty array.

So either you change `numberOfSectionsInTableView` to return `0` if the search results array is empty, or you change `titleForHeaderInSection` to return something different for the search results table.

Comment: thanks again :)

in numberOfSectionsInTableView I try this:
        if ([self searchResults])
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;

in titleForHeaderInSection I try this:

if ((tableView == [[self searchDisplayController]searchResultsTableView]) && [self searchResults])

but it not works. how can I check if the array is empty?
as you know I am new at obj c.

Comment: @Dennis: Use `if ([[self searchResults] count] == 0)` to check if array is empty.

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna check if the array contains objects before removing all objects from it..

```
if(dataSourceArray){  //use your datasource array instead
    [[self searchResults]removeAllObjects];
}
```